# C, detect cycle in directed graph, DFS, inconsistent graph

Tags: c, graph

i write program to detect cycle in directed graph, but on testing server is tests with inconsistent graph, and i don't know how change my program for this graph. I used DFS. For input like:

```
3 3 
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

is ok but i don't know how detect that graph is inconsistent, e.g for input:

```
5 4
1 2
2 3
4 5
5 4
```

First line of input is number of verticles and number of connection.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void dfs(int v, int reach[], int *tab[], int vert)
{
    int i;
    reach[v]=1;
    for(i=0;i<vert;i++)
    {
        if(tab[v][i]&&!reach[i])
        {
            dfs(i, reach, tab, vert);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //wczytaj wymiary
    int vert,edge, i, j, e1, e2, count;
   // printf("number of verticles: ");
    scanf("%d",&vert);
  //  printf("number of connections: ");
    scanf("%d",&edge);

    int *reach;
    int **tab;
    reach=(int*)malloc((vert+1)*sizeof(int));
    tab=(int**)malloc((vert+1)*sizeof(int *)); //alokacja pamieci
    for( i=0; i<vert; i++)
    {
        tab[i]=(int*)malloc((vert+1)*sizeof(int));
       // printf("ok\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<vert;i++)
    {
        reach[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<vert;j++)
        {
            tab[i][j]=0;
        }
    }



    for(i=0;i<edge;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &e1);
        scanf("%d", &e2);
        tab[e1-1][e2-1]=1;
       // printf("ok %d\n", tab[e1-1][e2-1]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<vert;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<vert;j++)
        {
           // printf("%d\n",tab[i][j]);
        }
    }

    dfs(1, reach, tab, vert);
   // printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<vert;i++)
    {
        if(reach[i])
            count++;
        printf("count: %d", count);
    }
    if(count==vert)
        printf("graph have cycle");
    else
        printf("graph doesn't have cycle");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is buggy code.
Lets take below example:

No of vertices = 4
Edges = 3

Edges from (2, 1) (2, 3) (2, 4)
tab[][] {0 0 0 0
         1 0 1 1
         0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0}

There is no cycle but this code says its cyclic graph.
As per my understanding ur only checking graph is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to at least check that your graph does not have the duplicated edges.

That can easily be done in that part of your code: instead of just assigning the entry, check if it was already been initialized. If yes, then your graph has duplicated edges.

```
for(i=0;i<edge;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &e1);
    scanf("%d", &e2);
    if (tab[e1-1][e2-1]==1) {
       printf("duplicated edge between %d and %d",e1, e2);
       exit(-1);
    } else tab[e1-1][e2-1]=1;
   // printf("ok %d\n", tab[e1-1][e2-1]);
}
```

Comment: in directed graph edge e1-e2 and e2-e1 are diffrent edges. and this edges create a cycle. problem is how find subgraph.

Comment: In your second example, you have two "5 4" entries.